# ¿por qué siempre aparece el mensaje de que la cantidad ingresada supera nuestro stock, si al colocar el dato es una cantidad inferior al stock?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, método

comunidad. Espero se encuentren bien. Tengo un simulador de compras de productos y allí existe un objeto Producto, el cual tiene un método (vender) pero por más que he tratado de hacer funcionar adecuadamente el condicional, no he podido. Cada vez que el usuario intenta colocar el numero correspondiente a la compra del producto, aparece el mensaje de que la cantidad ha superado el stock, siendo esta info errónea. He intentado cambiar los signos de mayor que y menor que, entre otras cosas y nada. Gracias de antemano.

```
const ingresarNombre = function(){
    return prompt("ingresar nombre y apellido");
}

const ingresarDNI = () => {
    return prompt("ingresar DNI");
}
const ingresarTelefono = function(){
    return (prompt("ingresar telefono de contacto"));
}


let nombre = ingresarNombre();
let DNI = ingresarDNI();
let telefono = ingresarTelefono();


console.log(nombre);
console.log(DNI);
console.log(telefono);


function registrarComprador(nombre, DNI, telefono){
    return "se registro al comprador "+nombre + ", nro DNI: "+DNI + " te contactaremos por la entrega de tu compra al telefono: " +telefono;
}

alert (registrarComprador(nombre, DNI, telefono));


class Producto {
    constructor (nombre, precio, cantidad) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = parseFloat(precio);
    this.cantidad = parseInt(cantidad);
   }

    vender(){
     let cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar cantidad"));
        if (this.cantidad >= cantidad){
                this.cantidad -= cantidad;
            }
        if (this.cantidad < cantidad){
                alert ("La cantidad ingresada supera nuestro stock, te pedimos que ingreses una cantidad menor.");
                }
        }
    }


const producto1 = new Producto("pan de campo", 300, 30);
const producto2 = new Producto("pan de molde", 270, 24);
const producto3 = new Producto("budin organico", 250, 15);
const producto4 = new Producto("pizza estilo napoles", 400, 20);


console.log(producto1);
alert("Producto 1: Pan de campo")
producto1.vender();
console.log(producto1);

console.log(producto2);
alert("producto 2: pan de molde")
producto2.vender();
console.log(producto2);

console.log(producto3);
alert("producto 3: budin organico")
producto3.vender();
console.log(producto3);

console.log(producto4);
alert("producto 4: pizza estilo napoles")
producto4.vender();
console.log(producto4);

alert("tu compra fue aprobada: " + " te vamos a estar contactando al telefono " + telefono + " para coordinar tu entrega")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque si hay stock y le restas a este la cantidad que ingresada e inmediatamente vuelves a preguntar por el stock, es probable que ya no tengas porque el anterior le quitó. No puedes quitar el stock y volver a preguntar por el stock. Invierte los `if`.

```
vender(){
     let cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar cantidad"));
        
        if (this.cantidad < cantidad){
                alert ("La cantidad ingresada supera nuestro stock, te pedimos que ingreses una cantidad menor.");
                }
         else{
                this.cantidad -= cantidad;
            }

        }
    }
```